# Jquery multi-select plugin which maintains ordering after form submission

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have searched a lot but I am unable to find a multiple select jquery  plugin which maintains selection order after form submission.

For example, there are 10 cities in a selectbox which is populated dynamically. If I select, Boston then Los Angeles, and submit the form, it should maintain that order. But what I see is that after submitting, it maintains the order in that they load in DOM. I have tried chosen and other plugins but I am still unable to achieve the desired results.

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".chosen-select").chosen();

```
    var MY_SELECT = $($(".chosen-select").get(0));


    $('#s1-get-order').click(function()
    {

        var selection = MY_SELECT.getSelectionOrder();
        $("#s1-input-order").val(selection); 

        $('#s1-order-list').empty();
        $(selection).each(function(i)
        {
            $('#s1-order-list').append("<li>"+selection[i]+"</li>");
        });
    });


$('#s1-set-order').click(function()
    {
        MY_SELECT.setSelectionOrder($('#s1-input-order').val().split(','), true);
    });
// Object-oriented flavor, example for jQuery plugin
    var selection = $('.chosen-select').getSelectionOrder();
    //alert(selection);

    var order = selection;
    //alert(order);
    $('.chosen-select').setSelectionOrder(order, true);




});
```

This is the code, that I have tried in chosen plugin to maintain the order. As you see, I have used chosen plugin with its add-on chosen order. I retrieved the order but I am unable to set the order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
$(function() {

$('select[multiple].chosen').chosen();

function getVal(str) {
  var selVal    = $($('select[name='+str+']').get(0));
  return selVal.getSelectionOrder();
}

function setVal(str) {
  var selVal    = $($('select[name='+str+']').get(0));
  selVal.setSelectionOrder($('#btnWriteList').val().split(','), true);
}


function listVal(str) {
  var ar1 = getVal(str);
  $('#btnReadList').empty();
  $(ar1).each(function(i) {
    $('#btnReadList').append("<li>"+ar1[i]+"</li>");
  });
}

//############ Read ######################
  $('#btnRead').click(function() {
  listVal('sel2');
});

//############ Write ####################
$('#btnWrite').click(function() {
  setVal('sel2');
});
```